# select fre:ac snap to run when audio CD is in drive

Tags: snap, system-settings, optical

In Ubuntu settings, there are options for the handling of removable media, for example to select what happens if one puts a CD into its drive. 
Inside there's a list of different software to choose from. Some programs installed as snap do show up, others don't. fre:ac isn't in the list. Is there a way to select it for starting automatically on CD-in-drive?